# Pandas - forward and backwards fill by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has this overall structure:
*(I know. It could be better, but this is what i have to work with :)*

```
| patient_id | inclusion_timestamp | pre_event_1      | post_event_1     | post_event_2     |
|------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 1          | NaN                 | 27-06-2020 12:26 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 1          | 28-06-2020 13:05    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 1          | NaN                 | NaN              | 29-06-2020 14:00 | NaN              |
| 1          | NaN                 | NaN              | NaN              | 29-06-2020 23:57 |
| 2          | NaN                 | 29-06-2020 10:11 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 2          | 29-06-2020 18:26    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 2          | NaN                 | NaN              | 30-06-2020 19:36 | NaN              |
| 2          | NaN                 | NaN              | NaN              | 31-06-2020 21:20 |
| 3          | NaN                 | 29-06-2020 06:35 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | NaN                 | 29-06-2020 07:28 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | 30-06-2020 09:06    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | NaN                 | NaN              | NaN              | 01-07-2020 12:10 |
```

and so forth.

The only way i know to do calculations from the inclusion_timestamp, is to fill forward from the inclusion_timestamp. However, this will yield wrong calculations for the pre_event_1 field, as it's column typically precedes the value for calculation.

Is there any way to do forward and backwards fill but only on the same index_col(patient_id)?
This way, the resulting dataframe will look like so:

```
| patient_id | inclusion_timestamp | pre_event_1      | post_event_1     | post_event_2     |
|------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 1          | 28-06-2020 13:05    | 27-06-2020 12:26 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 1          | 28-06-2020 13:05    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 1          | 28-06-2020 13:05    | NaN              | 29-06-2020 14:00 | NaN              |
| 1          | 28-06-2020 13:05    | NaN              | NaN              | 29-06-2020 23:57 |
| 2          | 29-06-2020 18:26    | 29-06-2020 10:11 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 2          | 29-06-2020 18:26    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 2          | 29-06-2020 18:26    | NaN              | 30-06-2020 19:36 | NaN              |
| 2          | 29-06-2020 18:26    | NaN              | NaN              | 31-06-2020 21:20 |
| 3          | 30-06-2020 09:06    | 29-06-2020 06:35 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | 30-06-2020 09:06    | 29-06-2020 07:28 | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | 30-06-2020 09:06    | NaN              | NaN              | NaN              |
| 3          | 30-06-2020 09:06    | NaN              | NaN              | 01-07-2020 12:10 |
```

I think that the answer is to iterate over the index column, and then apply forward and backwards fill within each patient_id, but i can't get my code to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `patient_id` and using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
df['inclusion_timestamp'] = df.groupby('patient_id')['inclusion_timestamp']\
                              .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Or another idea using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
g = df.groupby('patient_id')['inclusion_timestamp']
df['inclusion_timestamp'] = g.ffill().combine_first(g.bfill())
```

Another idea using two successive [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
df['inclusion_timestamp'] = df['inclusion_timestamp'].groupby(df['patient_id'])\
                           .ffill().groupby(df['patient_id']).bfill()
```

Result:

```
    patient_id inclusion_timestamp       pre_event_1      post_event_1      post_event_2
0            1    28-06-2020 13:05  27-06-2020 12:26               NaN               NaN
1            1    28-06-2020 13:05               NaN               NaN               NaN
2            1    28-06-2020 13:05               NaN  29-06-2020 14:00               NaN
3            1    28-06-2020 13:05               NaN               NaN  29-06-2020 23:57
4            2    29-06-2020 18:26  29-06-2020 10:11               NaN               NaN
5            2    29-06-2020 18:26               NaN               NaN               NaN
6            2    29-06-2020 18:26               NaN  30-06-2020 19:36               NaN
7            2    29-06-2020 18:26               NaN               NaN  31-06-2020 21:20
8            3    30-06-2020 09:06  29-06-2020 06:35               NaN               NaN
9            3    30-06-2020 09:06  29-06-2020 07:28               NaN               NaN
10           3    30-06-2020 09:06               NaN               NaN               NaN
11           3    30-06-2020 09:06               NaN               NaN  01-07-2020 12:10
```

Performance (measured using `timeit`):

```
df.shape
(1200000, 5)

%%timeit -n10 @Method 1 (Best Method)
263 ms ± 1.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @Method 2
342 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit -n10 @Method3
297 ms ± 4.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Both of your answers works perfectly.
Thank you so much. I have never been good at how to use lambda functions. Can you point me to a good resource?

Comment: Take a look at this [official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html), i think you might find it helpful.